# What exactly is the 'vertexPosition_modelspace' attribute

Tags: c++, opengl

I am new to OpenGL and was doing [this](http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/beginners-tutorials/tutorial-2-the-first-triangle/) tutorial.
This was in the vertex shader code:

```
layout(location = 0) in vec3 vertexPosition_modelspace;
```

I understand what layout is doing, but could not find anything about vertexPosition_modelspace

Comment: It's an attribute, it's not a keyword (syntax), same as defining variable

Comment: This line could be interpreted as follows, I am going to use a buffer (x) specified by layout to add some value  (`vec3 type`) to `vertexPosition_modelspace`.

Comment: Okay thank you for explaining!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Explained by m-zayan:

> It's an attribute, it's not a keyword (syntax), same as defining variable  This line could be interpreted as follows, I am going to use a buffer (x) specified by layout to add some value (vec3 type) to vertexPosition_modelspace